# How to split a tar file and capture the tar errors in a log?

Tags: linux, bash, split, tar

I'm attempting to tar a folder and piping it to the 'split' command, which I'm used to. However, I'm failing to combine this with an error output to a log.

```
tar -cvf - folder 1 2 > tar.log | split -b 20000MB - /path/to/file1.tar
```

I've also tried

```
tar -cvf - folder 1&2 > tar.log | split -b 20000MB - /path/to/file1.tar
```

and

```
tar -cvf - folder | split -b 20000MB - /path/to/file1.tar 1 2 > tar.log
```

To no avail...

What I'm getting is either the tarball and error mixed into the tar.log file and no .tar file at all, or a command failure

What's my mistake here?

Comment: `(tar cvf - folder | split -b 20000MB - /path/to/file1.tar ) 2> tar.log` or `tar cvf - folder 2>tar.log | split -b 20000MB - /path/to/file1.tar 2> split.log`

Answer (score 0):

You have a tiny mistake in your first and second line, it should read:

```
tar -cvf - folder 2> tar.log | split -b 20000MB - /path/to/file1.tar
```

This is called redirection. I do not understand what you tried to attempt with `1&2`